# UPDATE table with checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql

I have the facility to update what I call 'documents' (ver similar to creating a post) on my cms which works fine but I have introduced categories where the documents are associated to them. Now I have managed to bind them when creating the doc from new but when trying update them I am getting a bit stuck. I am using checkboxes to show the list of categories and when selected it updates a join table which uses the doc_id and the cat_id.

Here is the script for updating the doc:

```
<?php

include ('includes/header.php'); 
require ('../../db_con.php'); 

echo '<h1>Document Edit</h1>';

// Check for a valid document ID, through GET or POST:
if ( (isset($_GET['id'])) && (is_numeric($_GET['id'])) ) { // From view_docs.php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
} elseif ( (isset($_POST['id'])) && (is_numeric($_POST['id'])) ) { // Form submission.
    $id = $_POST['id'];
} else { // No valid ID, kill the script.
    echo '<p class="error">This page has been accessed in error.</p>';
    exit();
}


// Check if the form has been submitted:
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $errors = array();

    // Check for a document name:
    if (empty($_POST['doc_name'])) {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your document name.';
    } else {
        $dn = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['doc_name']));
    }

    // Check for a document content:
    if (empty($_POST['doc_content'])) {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your last name.';
    } else {
        $dc = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['doc_content']));
    }



    if (empty($errors)) { // If everything's OK.

        //  Test for unique doc title:
        $q = "SELECT doc_id FROM docs WHERE doc_name='$dn' AND doc_id != $id";

        $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 0) {

            // Make the query:
            $q = "UPDATE docs SET doc_name='$dn', doc_content='$dc', doc_name='$dn' WHERE doc_id=$id LIMIT 1";

            $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

            if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) { // If it ran OK.




            $doc_id = mysqli_insert_id($dbc); 

            $query = "UPDATE doc_cat_join (cat_id,doc_id) VALUES "; 
            $cat_ids = $_POST['cat_id']; 
            $length = count($cat_ids); 
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($cat_ids); $i++) { 
            $query.='(' . $cat_ids[$i] . ',' . $doc_id . ')'; 

            if ($i < $length - 1) 
            $query.=','; 
            } 




                // Print a message:
                echo '<p>The document has been edited.</p>';    

            } else { // If it did not run OK.
                echo '<p class="error">The document could not be edited due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>'; // Public message.
                echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br />Query: ' . $q . '</p>'; // Debugging message.
            }

        } else { // Already used.
            echo '<p class="error">The document name has already been used.</p>';
        }

    } else { // Report the errors.

        echo '<p class="error">The following error(s) occurred:<br />';
        foreach ($errors as $msg) { // Print each error.
            echo " - $msg<br />\n";
        }
        echo '</p><p>Please try again.</p>';

    } // End of if (empty($errors)) IF.

} // End of submit conditional.

// Always show the form...

// Retrieve the document's information:
$q = "SELECT * FROM docs WHERE doc_id=$id"; 

$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) { // Valid document ID, show the form.

    // Get the document's information:
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_NUM);


    // Create the form:
    echo '<form action="edit_doc.php" method="post">

    <p>Document Name: <input type="text" name="doc_name" size="15" maxlength="15" value="' . $row[1] . '" /></p>

    <textarea name="doc_content" id="doc_content" placeholder="Document Content" style="display: none;"></textarea>
    <iframe name="editor" id="editor" ></iframe>'
        ?>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-group-1"> 
            <?php

            $q = "SELECT * FROM cats";  

            $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.

            echo '<div class="view_body">';

            // FETCH AND PRINT ALL THE RECORDS
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
            echo '<br><label><input type="checkbox" name="cat_id[]" value="' . $row['cat_id'] . '">' . $row["cat_name"] . '</label>';
            }
            echo '</div>'; 

            ?>
        </div>
    </div>       


    <br><br> 
    <input onclick="formsubmit()" type="submit" value="Update Document" name="submit"/>

    <?php echo'

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $id . '" />
</form>
<br><br><a href="list_doc.php">Back to docs list</a>';

} else { // Not a valid document ID.
    echo '<p class="error">This page has been accessed in error.</p>';
}

?>

<?php
    mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

So I have three tables:

```
docs
  doc_id
  doc_name
  doc_content

cats
  cat_id
  cat_name

doc_cat_join
  doc_id
  cat_id
```

the join table related the doc_id and cat_id which then associates them together. I am guessing in my script when I update a doc it will need to delete the rows and then re-insert them? I just need to know a way or the easiest way of updating the join table as I am a tad stuck...

Comment: That's pretty big code. Please shorten it.

Comment: Why you use  `LIMIT` in update query???

Comment: @Saty sorry I do not understand what you mean?

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com I didnt copy anything from PHPmyadmin

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com LIMIT can be a security logic in update statement

Comment: @donald123 That is precisely why it is there.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com I have condensed the code down now - any suggestions on my approach here?

Comment: @donald123 Any suggestions on how I may approach this at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of checkbox update you need to delete previous stored checkbox of with appropriate id and insert new one you can't update checkbox as we can't predict how many checkbox will be selected by user....

**Case:**

It may happen that user remove one checkbox at update time so you will never know which one to be deleted.......

In your code...

```
docs
   doc_id
   doc_name
   doc_content

cats
   cat_id
   cat_name

doc_cat_join
   id
   doc_id
   cat_id
```

here you have to delete old checkbox of updation doc,

```
DELETE FROM doc_cat_join WHERE cat_id = some_id
```

next you can insert selected checkbox as you are inserting first time...

Comment: that is exactly right, a user may remove categories the document is associated to, i am new to this could you possibly expand on your suggestion?

Comment: Ok so I understand the theory around this which would make perfect sense to remove any entries and then re-insert up submission to ensure there are no dupe entries - BUT I am not sure in my code where this would live or how to implement this? Could you show me from my code above a small example?

Comment: you are inserting comma separated but may be better approach is to insert individually

Comment: Ok, what would be a better approach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81851/discussion-between-phpcoder-and-sagar-naliyapara).